# Returned document showing unexpected values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Schema defined using `Mongoose`

```
  const IndustryPartnerSchema = new Schema({
  mentors: [{ user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" } }],
});

module.exports = IndustryPartner = mongoose.model(
  "IndustryPartner",
  IndustryPartnerSchema
);
```

And I have the following stored in my DB

```
 "mentors" : [
        ObjectId("5c9ba825347bb645e0865293")
    ]
```

However, when I query the DB using,

```
   IndustryPartner.findOne({ _id: req.query.partnerId })
      .populate("mentors")
```

I get the following:

```
{ "mentors": []}
```

IF I remove `.populate("mentors")`, I get the following:

```
  "mentors": [
        {
            "_bsontype": "ObjectID",
            "id": {
                "type": "Buffer",
                "data": [
                    92,
                    155,
                    168,
                    37,
                    52,
                    123,
                    182,
                    69,
                    224,
                    134,
                    82,
                    147
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

There has to be something I am missing, I know the ObjectId is valid because I manually searched my DB for it and it is a valid User document. Why isn't this actually populating the field?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mentors` field in your schema is an array of object with `user` field is ObjectId so your record in the DB is not match with the schema. As you already saved record in DB so you need to change your schema like the below to make it work:

```
const IndustryPartnerSchema = new Schema({
  mentors: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
});
```

Comment: Wow, definitely missed that, thank you. Always takes another set of eyes!